# How do create an upload option in AppScript for a form?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating a reimbursement form script, where if I run the script it will create a Google Form. What do I write in the Script so I can create an upload option in the form? I don't see any upload option in .add

Comment: That feature is not available in google apps script.  You can use an html form to accomplish it if you wish.

Comment: As @Cooper mentioned there's no such a feature at the moment, you can let them know as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing_features) specifies.